# Access 2016 form button to open report based on current record

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-reports

I'm trying to create a button on a form that will open a report with just the current record.

I've done the following:

- created a button
- created Event Procedure for On Click (it opens macro mode instead of Visual Basic)
- modified the Where Condition with various entries

Since the settings are in macro mode, I'm not sure how to post the macro code, so I'll enter it as a list.

- **OpenReport**
- **Report Name:** Awards by Category - Single
- **View:** Print Preview
- **Filter Name:** blank
- **Where Condition =** [Registrants]![EventName]=[Me].[EventName]
- **Window Mode:** blank

**Expected results** - clicking on button opens report showing just the current record

**Actual results** - clicking on button opens Enter Parameter Value dialog box asking to enter value for Me.EventName. When I enter current EventName, the report opens with the correct record showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest changing the **Where Condition** of your macro to:

```
[Registrants]![EventName]=[Forms]![YourFormName]![EventName]
```

(Changing `YourFormName` to the name of your form)

Your current macro fails because `Me` is a VBA keyword (which refers to an instance of the class in which the current code is executing) and is therefore not applicable in this context.